# Javascript: navigate table inputs with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an HTML grade book for a client. I am generating the gradebook with PHP, and then outputting a HTML table as seen in the example below. Each `<td>` contains a div with an `<input>` for the teacher to type in the student's score.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: how can I make it so the teacher can use the arrow keys on the keyboard to navigate inside of the gradebook? IE: The teacher should be able to click a cell, type in a grade, and then hit the left/right/up/down arrow key to move to the appropriate input and type in the next grade.

I have seen numerous examples on here about how to use javascript to accomplish this task in highlighting different `<td>` cells, but I cannot figure out how I would go about allowing the teacher to navigate inputs with her arrow keys. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 105px; left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100vh - 105px);
     background-color: #FCFCFC;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
     grid-template-areas:
       "master"}

   .master {
     grid-area: master;
     overflow-x: scroll;}

   table {border-collapse: collapse}

   th, td {
     background-color: white;
     max-width: 110px;
     border: 1px solid lightgray;}

   th {overflow: hidden;}

  thead{
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;}

  tr td:nth-child(1),
  tr th:nth-child(1){
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;}

   thead th.navigator { /* Top left cell with navigation controls */
     padding: 10px;
     z-index: 3;}

   tr td:first-child, tr td:nth-child(2) { /* First two columns of each row */
     white-space: nowrap;
     max-width: fit-content !important;}

   td input {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 80%;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding: 6px 0px;
     cursor: cell;}

   th select {
     outline: none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 8px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid lightgray}

  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) {background-color: #E9DCF9}
  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) input {background-color: #E9DCF9}

  .due {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkgray;}

   .assign {padding: 20px}
   .assign span {
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #581F98}

   .avg {padding: 10px}

   .studentInfo {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 10px 12px 10px 6px;}

   .studentInfo img {
     width: 25px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     clip-path: circle();}

   .red {background-color: red;}
   .gray, .gray input {background-color: #F2F2F2;}

  .score {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}
```

```html
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='navigator' colspan='2' rowspan='4'>
                <form method='GET'>
                  <select name='subID' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                    <option value='1' >Reading</option>
                    <option value='2' >Social Studies</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name='week' onchange='this.form.submit()' disabled>
                    <option value='all'>Entire Quarter</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
              </th>
              <tr>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/11</span> to <span title='Wednesday'>10/13</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/18</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 130' onclick='assignInfo("130");'> Quiz</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 146' onclick='assignInfo("146");'> Homework</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 145' onclick='assignInfo("145");'> Test</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 147' onclick='assignInfo("147");'>✏️ Project</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='9.111/10'>91%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.672/10'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='4.348/5'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.007/10'>80%</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 11'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/11.jpg'></span>
                <span>John Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='11' title='97.5/110'>89%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='11' data-workID='7282' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='11' data-workID='7340' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 12'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/12.jpg'></span>
                <span>Jane Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='12' title='97.5/110'>69%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7250' data-curScore='6' value='6'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='12' data-workID='7211' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='12' data-workID='7110' data-curScore='4' value='4'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7233' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 13'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/13.jpg'></span>
                <span>Sally Martin</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='13' title='97.5/110'>100%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='6250' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='13' data-workID='6211' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='13' data-workID='7610' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='7933' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Just use the Tab Key. But if you really want to use arrow keys, you have to add some JavaScript to your code. You could try something with an event listener to focus some element based on your input.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a spreadsheet editor. You may want to look for a client side library that can do this for you.

Comment: @TheOrigin tab key would only work to move right, but I need to move up/down also.

Comment: @Kyle I'm not sure I would even know where to begin with that. I really don't need many editor features, only the ability to move up/down with arrow keys.

Comment: As @TheOrigin says you'll need some js, listen for keydown event, get the cell index you're in, then depending on the key pressed (arrows)  go from there by  getting the right element in your table and focus the input with input.focus().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not perfect but it should give you a place to start. You'll have to add some error handling and handle edge cases.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', ( event ) => {

  const currentInput = document.activeElement;
  const currentTd = currentInput.parentNode.parentNode;
  const currentTr = currentTd.parentNode;
  const index = Array.from(currentTr.children).indexOf(currentTd);

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowLeft":
        // Left pressed
        currentTd.previousElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":
        // Right pressed
        currentTd.nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
        break;
    case "ArrowUp":
        // Up pressed
        Array.from( currentTr.previousElementSibling.children )[index].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
        break;
    case "ArrowDown":
        // Down pressed
        Array.from( currentTr.nextElementSibling.children )[index].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
        break;
  }
} )
```

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 105px; left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100vh - 105px);
     background-color: #FCFCFC;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
     grid-template-areas:
       "master"}

   .master {
     grid-area: master;
     overflow-x: scroll;}

   table {border-collapse: collapse}

   th, td {
     background-color: white;
     max-width: 110px;
     border: 1px solid lightgray;}

   th {overflow: hidden;}

  thead{
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;}

  tr td:nth-child(1),
  tr th:nth-child(1){
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;}

   thead th.navigator { /* Top left cell with navigation controls */
     padding: 10px;
     z-index: 3;}

   tr td:first-child, tr td:nth-child(2) { /* First two columns of each row */
     white-space: nowrap;
     max-width: fit-content !important;}

   td input {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 80%;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding: 6px 0px;
     cursor: cell;}

   th select {
     outline: none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 8px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid lightgray}

  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) {background-color: #E9DCF9}
  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) input {background-color: #E9DCF9}

  .due {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkgray;}

   .assign {padding: 20px}
   .assign span {
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #581F98}

   .avg {padding: 10px}

   .studentInfo {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 10px 12px 10px 6px;}

   .studentInfo img {
     width: 25px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     clip-path: circle();}

   .red {background-color: red;}
   .gray, .gray input {background-color: #F2F2F2;}

  .score {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}
```

```html
<table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='navigator' colspan='2' rowspan='4'>
                <form method='GET'>
                  <select name='subID' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                    <option value='1' >Reading</option>
                    <option value='2' >Social Studies</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name='week' onchange='this.form.submit()' disabled>
                    <option value='all'>Entire Quarter</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
              </th>
              <tr>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/11</span> to <span title='Wednesday'>10/13</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/18</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 130' onclick='assignInfo("130");'> Quiz</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 146' onclick='assignInfo("146");'> Homework</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 145' onclick='assignInfo("145");'> Test</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 147' onclick='assignInfo("147");'>✏️ Project</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='9.111/10'>91%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.672/10'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='4.348/5'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.007/10'>80%</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 11'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/11.jpg'></span>
                <span>John Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='11' title='97.5/110'>89%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='11' data-workID='7282' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='11' data-workID='7340' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 12'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/12.jpg'></span>
                <span>Jane Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='12' title='97.5/110'>69%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7250' data-curScore='6' value='6'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='12' data-workID='7211' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='12' data-workID='7110' data-curScore='4' value='4'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7233' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 13'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/13.jpg'></span>
                <span>Sally Martin</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='13' title='97.5/110'>100%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='6250' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='13' data-workID='6211' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='13' data-workID='7610' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='7933' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```